# Table header and body spacing independently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted my table to scroll while leaving the header in tact. When I did so it created a separation of the `th` and the `tbody`. now I cannot get it to format properly.

I am getting output where the header and body are spacing independently of each other. Here is a `fiddle` of my issue. http://jsfiddle.net/EWfd8/

Comment: Quick suggestion at first glance of your code. You should keep it organized in the HTML and CSS files. It looks mashed together and makes it more difficult to read. I cleaned it up for you. Ill take a look at it in a bit.

Comment: Yea, sorry. realizing it is hard to read. Might do an edit on fiddle in a bit. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<tbody></tbody>` of your code, or place it before the `<th>`.